# Reasons for subsequent Broken/missing handler in Views?

Tags: 7, views, upgrading

In the process of upgrading Drupal 6.x to 7.x I'm facing a problem that makes all my views show nothing relevant. (I believe the problem is here but I'm not sure, I don't know. That's why I'm asking):

After using the migrate field from CCK module in Drupal 7.x most of my views end up with *Broken/missing handler* whether it is in *Field*, *Filters Criteria* or *Relationships*.

On the other side, when using the migrate field module, most of the fields have a message similar to this attached with them. (The field names change.)

> Missing formatter: The 'hidden' formatter used in 3 view modes for the field_phone field is not available, these displays will be reset to the default formatter.

Or I get this message.

> Changed field type: The 'field_source_file' field type will be changed from 'filefield' to 'file'.

Or I get this message one too.

> The field uses the view list_of_project_for_captain_log to determine referenceable nodes. You will need to manually edit the view and add a display of type 'References'.

Is this the reason why most the views have a Broken/missing handler than makes them not work properly? If yes, what can I do, if not what else could be the reason for such problems and what should be done?

Comment: Rather than trying to migrate the views, I'd suggest recreating them from scratch. It might be a slog but probably easier unless you have a huge number of views.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have indeed a lot of views unfortunately. I'm not the one who created them in the first place, so it's kind of hard to recreate them I guess. Thank you for answering!

Comment: In that case I'd bring a up a Drupal 6 install where they still work and look at how the handlers were configured. If you take just one view as a test case and try to understand it as completely as possible (examining the code from an export may help), you should be able to identify at least one handler which was present in the D6 version but not in D7. When you know that, post the answer here.

Comment: I have upgraded several sites, and some of this is absolutely unavoidable. But I quickly learned to upgrade views only after all of the fields and other modules had been done to put everything in place before the views went looking for something that was not yet present. The instructions on Drupal.org should state, clearly, to wait and upgrade views last. Remember, many of these handlers are implemented in contributed modules.

Comment: Thank you fo your insight. I indeed upgraded every module before passing to content migrate and finally views. Well then, I'll stick to that for now.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the following guides:

- [Upgrading Drupal core](https://drupal.org/documentation/upgrade)
- [Migrating D6 Content Construction Kit (CCK) to D7 Fields](https://drupal.org/node/1144136)
- [Migrating image fields](https://drupal.org/node/1339962)

Also:

- Make sure that you've enabled all the field modules such as image and views related
- *Changed field type: The 'field_source_file' field type
  will be changed from 'filefield' to 'file'* is just information; it's nothing to worry about
- To fix the *Broken/missing handler* message, you have to identify the right modules which provide these handlers and enable them

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is that while migration to Drupal 7 you have to maintain the machine names as same. If they change during the migration or don't get migrated due to some reason, you will for sure find views or fields as broken.

You need to be careful while migration for fields those don't migrate. Note them down, either manually create them first on D7 and then run migration or create some custom plugin files for migration of those fields.